What is the meaning of Romans 12:21?
Romans 12:21 declares:

Do not be overcome by evil, but overcome evil with good.

How does one overcome evil?

Does not the text answer the question?  "...overcome evil with good".

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE Salvatore. We are glad you are here. If you haven't, consider taking a moment to take the site tour and check out educating new users and the FAQs. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

How does one overcome evil? By doing that which is good. The answer is very simple, but the application may not be.
Vengeance is not a sign of strength, but of weakness. Two wrongs don't make a right.
Romans 12:20-21 says,

Therefore “If your enemy is hungry, feed him; If he is thirsty, give
him a drink; For in so doing you will heap coals of fire on his head.”
Do not be overcome by evil, but overcome evil with good.

Overcome (nikaó) is a word for battle that means:

Definition: to conquer, prevail Usage: I conquer, am victorious,
overcome, prevail, subdue.

We are being told that evil can be disarmed with good. It’s about breaking the cycle of negativity and hostility by choosing the higher path. Overcoming evil with good is perhaps the highest form of moral victory. It demonstrates strength of character and resilience of spirit. It’s a principle that encourages forgiveness over vengeance, love over hate, and peace over conflict.

Paul seems to have in mind the idea that we are overcome by evil when
we join in and give it back, when we sink to evil's level. That just
results in more sin, more pain, and an endless cycle of revenge and
hatred.
In other words, evil wins when we live first for ourselves, our
rights, and our own good, instead of the good of others. (bibleref)

Charles Spurgeon once argued in his 1876 sermon Overcome Evil with Good, “You must either be overcome of evil, or you must yourself overcome evil; one of the two. You cannot let evil alone and evil will not let you alone. You must fight, and in the battle you must either conquer or be conquered.”

As has already been quoted, the verses immediately before the verse in question give many examples of what kind of good things Christians should be swift to do, in their stance against evil. The verse, however, implies an important point at the start, namely, that something has to be done in the face of evil, otherwise the evil may overcome an individual.
Christians cannot be neutral about evil, for this evil is active, and has an agenda - a purpose - because the evil one is at the back of all evil (1 Peter 5:8). Unseen, yes, but acting through human agencies that love the darkness rather than the light of Christ (John 3:19-20).
When Christians understand that, then they know what they are really up against, when evil is done to them. As ambassadors for Christ, they are the targets of the evil one. He is their real enemy, not the hateful individuals who are manipulated and deceived by him. That is why Jesus commanded loving one's enemies, and praying for them (Matthew 5:44).
Doing those various good things to their enemies (as listed in the previous verses) is showing love to them - symbolically heaping coals on their heads. This suggests that to do good to one's enemies just to make them feel wretched about what they've done to the Christians is missing the point of Jesus' command; agape love seeks the good of the other, whether they deserve to have good done to them or not. The best good a Christian can do to an enemy is to show the love of Christ to them, practically, but also in words. Thus praying is included in doing them good.
The point about "overcoming" needs further examination, for there is more to that than 'just' actively doing good to one's enemies. Consider these texts about how to overcome evil:
"I have overcome the world." (Jesus speaking) John 16:33  "...ye have overcome the wicked one." (Christians) 1 John 2:13 & 14  "And they overcame him [the accuser of Christ's brethren] by the blood of the Lamb and the word of their testimony."  Revelation 12:11. Another powerful text is this:

"For whatsoever is born of God overcometh the world: and this is the
victory that overcometh the world, even our faith. Who is he that
overcometh the world? But he that believeth that Jesus is the Son of
God."  1John 5:4-5 A.V.

This means that doing good in itself requires faith in Christ having overcome the world; it requires being born of God; it requires faith in Jesus as the Son of God; it requires speaking one's testimony that is based on "the blood of the Lamb", not supposing one's own deeds and words will defeat the evil. It's only because Jesus has first overcome that Christians can become overcomers. In his power, they can do good to those who do them evil.

Paul clarifies what he means in the passage leading up to the verse quoted in the OP.

9 Let love be sincere; hate what is evil, hold on to what is good;
10 love one another with mutual affection; anticipate one another in
showing honor. 11 Do not grow slack in zeal, be fervent in spirit,
serve the Lord. 12 Rejoice in hope, endure in affliction, persevere
in prayer. 13 Contribute to the needs of the holy ones, exercise
hospitality. 14 Bless those who persecute [you], bless and do
not curse them. 15 Rejoice with those who rejoice, weep with those
who weep. 16 Have the same regard for one another; do not be
haughty but associate with the lowly; do not be wise in your own
estimation. 17 Do not repay anyone evil for evil; be concerned for
what is noble in the sight of all. 18 If possible, on your part,
live at peace with all. 19 Beloved, do not look for revenge but
leave room for the wrath; for it is written, “Vengeance is mine, I
will repay, says the Lord.” 20 Rather, “if your enemy is hungry,
feed him; if he is thirsty, give him something to drink; for by so
doing you will heap burning coals upon his head.”

Conclusion: Paul taught that to overcome evil with good, one has to manifest unconditional love - in other words we need to practice what Jesus peached in the gospels, especially Sermon on the Mount.
